# Как получить путь к файлу, если известен только его id?

Tags: php

товарищи!

Мне необходимо написать функцию удаления файла — физически и записи его в БД. Проблема в том, что я не могу получить его путь в контроллере, известно только id. А запись из БД удалить не проблема (в БД поля — id(integer), path(text) и dateAdded(text)). Файл должен удаляться по ссылке (в моём случае это — /test.org/admin/file/1, где «1» — его id). Вот Такой контроллер:

```
public function deleteFile(HTTPRequest $req): void
{
    // Это, конечно же, не работает
    // $path = $req->getData('path');
    // unlink($path);

    $this->fileManager->delete($req->getData('id'));
    $this->httpResponse->redirect('/admin/listFiles');
}
```

А это модель (для примера, к ней вопросов нет, она просто удалит строчку в БД и всё):

```
public function delete($id): void
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM files WHERE id = :id";
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindValue(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $req->execute();
}
```

Как бы получить путь к файлу? Буду рад любому толковому совету!

Comment: Почему закомментированный код не работает? Что хранится в пути файла в БД и почему его не использовать?

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, ну, я так полагаю, потому, что, NULL, ему же неоткуда взяться :). Ну, путь в БД в виде /Public/img/filename.jpg. А использовать в качестве чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, только сейчас додумался. Вот так работает:

```
// Контроллер
public function deleteFile(HTTPRequest $req): void
{
    $id = $req->getData('id');
    $file = $this->fileManager->path($id);
    $path = $file->getPath();
    unlink($path);
    $this->fileManager->delete($req->getData('id'));
    $this->httpResponse->redirect('/admin/listFiles');
}

// Модель
public function path($id) : ?File
{
    $sql = "SELECT path FROM files WHERE id = :id";
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindValue(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $req->execute();
    $req->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, File::class);
    $file= $req->fetch();
    return $file ?: null;
}

public function delete($id): void
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM files WHERE id = :id";
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindValue(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $req->execute();
}
```

Если кто-то предложит более рациональный код (например, упростить и сократить) — буду очень признателен :)

Answer (score 3):

у вас же в структуре записи в бд почти по русски написано — id(integer), **path(text)** и dateAdded(text))
вот в поле path и лежит путь к вашему файлу :)
SELECT path FROM files WHERE id = :id
и вы имеете свой путь.

Comment: А как из модели вытянуть в контроллер path? :) Запрос в контроллере писать как-то нехорошо же…

Comment: Ну вы же как-то удаляете запись в БД?  Значит написать запрос на удаление можно, а написать запрос на получение пути к файлу нельзя? Странная логика.

Comment: ну вот так и удаляю, в приведённом мною коде. Или вы к тому, что, если добавить SELECT path …, то, в контроллере к нему можно будет получить доступ через $req->getData('path')?

Comment: ну вы же как-то подключаетесь к базе данных ? через какой-то обьект db? а этот обьект очевидно может возвращать в каком-то виде значения, или рекордсет или датаридер... что -то такое, вот и покопайте в ту сторону.

Comment: Чего-то не того я написал. Выходит, в модели, нужно будет создать новую функцию для получения path? А как потом обращаться к нему из контроллера?

Comment: так же как и к функции delete

Comment: Ну вот как-то так: только не работает(
// Получение пути файла
 public function path($id): void
 {
  $sql = "SELECT path FROM files WHERE id = :id";
  $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
  $req->bindValue(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $req->execute();
 }

Comment: А это в контроллере  $path = $this->fileManager->path($req->getData('path'));